# How to do ANOVA analysis for therapeutic biomarker screening for drug sensitivity

Tags: anova, p-value, bioinformatics, genetics, sensitivity-analysis

I am new to Bioinformatics.

The graph below (from GDSC database) is to find **therapeutic biomarker for drug sensitivity**.
I wonder how to do this kind of **ANOVA** analysis on my own so as to make this kind of volcano plot.

I know how to calculate the IC50 Effect (x-axis), but I **don't know how to get the p-value (y-axis)**.

If drug IC50 is the only dependent variable (response) and gene mutations are the independent variables (factors),

**(1) is it correct to run one-way ANOVA analysis?**

**(2) how to obtain the p-value for each gene mutation? (is it just a p-value from t-test of drug IC50 between mutated group and wild-type group for each gene)**

Thx[image]

Comment: The ANOVA methods used are explained in detail on [this page](https://www.cancerrxgene.org/help#t_stats), near the bottom. Please look that over and make your question more specific based on what you think is still unanswered. Note that ANOVA for these particular data seems to be a multiple regression model involving a large number of cell lines and predictors, so this particular volcano plot will be hard to reproduce. Volcano plots in general are simply the (negative) log p-values plotted against the point estimates for the size of the effect, for a large number of related analyses.

Comment: thank u so much for yr reply.
I am still confused why anova is used instead of t-test if it is just the comparison of IC50 between mutated group and wild-type group of each gene.

I don't mean to reproduce this volcano plot. I have my own datasets of another drug and want to make another volcano plot like this one.

Answer (score 1):

For others who might visit this page, it's important to provide some detail on the underlying studies and the meaning of the plot.

These analyses start with individual IC50 values for a drug (a measure of sensitivity to a drug, smaller is better) on each of a large number of cell lines, label the cell lines with respect to several hundred known genomic and other features, and then look for associations of IC50 values with those features. They then transform the results for each genomic feature into an "IC50 effect" plotted along the horizontal axis, with a corresponding p-value (plotted as the negative of its logarithm) along the vertical axis.

The authors go down to features shared among as few as 3 cell lines, so  individual t-tests could be misleading with such a small number of observations. For such features you can have unrepresentative large or small variability among the values for the corresponding cell lines just due to random sampling. So even if the mean IC50 among them is quite low and of interest, a high variability among a few lines could lead you to call the result "insignificant" and thus you ignore a potentially important effect. Alternatively, the IC50 values for individual cell lines might just happen to be much more closely spaced than usual, leading to an over-estimate of the precision and a very small p-value that doesn't well represent reality for that feature.

One way to deal with this is to combine information about the error terms from multiple observations in multiple situations, to get overall error estimates that aren't so variable due to random sampling. That's what ANOVA does. It takes a sort of average error estimate based on the deviations of the results for each feature around the mean value for the feature. That prevents undue down- or up-weighting of individual features due to such small numbers of cases.

This wasn't done simply as a one-way ANOVA among the genomic features, as the [details](https://www.cancerrxgene.org/help#t_stats) show that they also incorporated information about factors including tissue type of the cancer cell line and the presence of micro-satellite instability (MSI) into their analysis along with the several hundred genomic features they evaluated. Although the authors call it ANOVA, ANOVA calculations these days use linear regression software so it's simpler to think in terms of a linear regression model.

In the linear regression, an estimated average IC50 value for a genomic feature was based on the IC50 values for each of the cell lines that had the feature, while taking the tissue type and MSI into account. The results are expressed as a regression coefficient for each feature, representing the difference from an overall intercept estimated from all the features. Information on variability was pooled among all the features to get an estimate of residual error.

I'm a bit unclear about how they calculated the "IC50 effect" for this plot as they cite 2 different methods, one using [Cohen's d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_d) and another using [Glass's $\Delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Glass%27_%CE%94). These are both ratios of differences between means to a measure of standard deviation. For Cohen's d they used the pooled standard deviation estimate from the ANOVA, and for the difference in means I presume they used for each feature its regression coefficient in the linear regression. Their description of Glass's $\Delta$ seems pretty straightforward; the standard deviation for each feature in that test is based on the very large number of cell lines that lack the corresponding feature, providing the pooling.

The p-values, the specific point of your question, "were obtained from the fitted models" for the drugs that were examined.The only "fitted model" for each drug was the original linear regression used to do the ANOVA, so the p-value for a feature would represent that for its regression coefficient in the regression, before the transformation of IC50 values into the "IC50 effect."

Comment: It is so detailed and clear! Really thanks so much for that.